# TypeScript type predicate

Tags: typescript

I have several union types, which are TypeScript types generated on the server.

Here's an example of the union type `A` and how it's used.

```
type KeysOfUnion<T> = T extends T ? keyof T : never;
export type ExtractValueTypeFromUnion<T, K extends KeysOfUnion<T>> = K extends string ?
    (T extends { [key in `${K}`]: infer ResultType } ?
        ResultType :
        never) :
    never

function isUnionVariant<U extends Record<string, any>, K extends KeysOfUnion<U>>(
    union: U,
    key: K
): union is K extends string ? { [key in `${K}`]: ExtractValueTypeFromUnion<U, K> } : never {
    return key in union;
}

type A = {
    "a": {
        a1: string
    }
} | {
    "b": {
        b1: string
    }
}

const doSomething = (a: A) => {
    if (isUnionVariant(a, "a")) {
        a.a.a1
    } else {
        a.b.b1
    }
}
```

The code functions correctly, but code editors (e.g. WebStorm) display an error:

```
TS2677: A type predicate's type must be assignable to its parameter's type.
```

in the type predicate:

```
K extends string ? { [key in `${K}`]: ExtractValueTypeFromUnion<U, K> } : never
```

This can be resolved by using `@ts-ignore`, but I would like assistance in eliminating the error without resorting to this workaround. I'm using TypeScript 5.2.2.

Comment: If the compiler cannot see that `X extends Y` then you can always use `X & Y` or `Extract<X, Y>` in place of `X`, depending on your needs. See [this version of your code](https://tsplay.dev/wXg8QW) for example. Does that fully address the question? If so I will write up an answer (or find a suitable duplicate target) If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thank you! This helps: `union is U &`

Comment: Great! Please see the linked q/a above for more information. The basic situation is that TS can't really analyze generic conditional types for assignability very well so you might need to "convince" it to accept the output as a narrowing with something like `&` or `Extract`.

Comment: You also seem to be using wildly overcomplicated types for a very simple situation. `if ("a" in a)` works just fine out of the box; you don’t need `isUnionVariant` at all. Even within `isUnionVariant`, you keep checking for `K extends string`, which may be necessary depending on your use case but you don’t need to do it so many times, and then after having done that you use `\`${K}\`` which is completely redundant when you’ve already checked `K extends string`. Would an answer that delves into these issues be useful to you?